# Async controller action returning a 302 redirect, is 'overtaken' by the next request

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-core-3.1

We are building an ASP.Net Core 3.1 application. It contains a page a list of work items and a form that allows some items to be assigned to someone. If the controller action  succeeds, it ends with a redirect to the action which shows the work items once more.

It noticed that sometimes the list is reloaded with some items with the old assignment and a refresh then gets the updated list.

The controller GET action for the list is async, with an await for the code that gets the list of items, with some nested code to get data form the database with a Linq to Entities query with `ToListAsync()`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    _log.Debug("Getting work items");
    List<Item> model = await _itemData.GetItems();
    return View(model);
}
```

The controller POST action is also async, but without any await.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int employeeId, int[] itemIds)
{
    _itemData.Assign(employeeId, itemIds);

    _log.Debug("Redirecting to work items");
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

However, code being called contains a construction like this:

```
public bool Assign(int employeeId, int[] itemIds)
{
    _log.Debug("Start assigning items");
    Array.ForEach(itemIds, async itemId =>
    {
        _log.Debug($"Done assigning item {itemId}");
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<context>();

            Item item = await db.Items.Where(i => i.Id == itemId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            item .EmployeeId= employeeId;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            _log.Debug($"Done assigning item {itemId}");
        }
    });

    _log.Debug("Done assigning items");
    return true;
}
```

*I have simplified the code quite a bit, and hope that I didn't introduce inconsistencies with that...*

I wonder how this actually works.

The loop is processed with an `async` instruction. This code await `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` and `SaveChangesAsync()`, but only within the loop. The logging reveals that the method itself returns before all awaited tasks have completed.

**Log**

```
Getting work items
Start assigning items
Start assigning item 1234
Start assigning report 2345
Done assigning item
Redirecting to work items
Getting work items
Done assigning item 1234
Done assigning item 2345
```

Is this expected behaviour?

I tried to make the `Assign()` method async and await its call, but as I expected, this did not change the results.

Can I combine an async assignment and awaiting the complete result in a fail safe way, or would it be best to simply change to a completely synchronous solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an asynchronous delegate to `Array.ForEach`, but you are not awaiting the completion of the tasks that are generated.

As alluded to by @JohanP, `Array.ForEach` doesn't work well with async code, because it accepts an `Action<T>` delegate, which has no return value meaning the tasks are lost.

Make your `Assign` method `async`:

```
public async Task<bool> Assign(int employeeId, int[] itemIds)
{
    _log.Debug("Start assigning items");
    using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<context>();
        var tasks = itemIds.Select(async itemId =>
        {
            _log.Debug($"Done assigning item {itemId}");

            Item item = await db.Items.Where(i => i.Id == itemId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            item.EmployeeId = employeeId;
            _log.Debug($"Done assigning item {itemId}");
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    _log.Debug("Done assigning items");
    return true;
}
```

Notice how `Task.WhenAll` ensures that all the tasks have been awaited before your method is allowed to return.

Using `Enumerable.Select` will allow the async work to happen in parallel, unlike the `foreach` approach suggested by @Paulo.

`SaveChangesAsync` should be called once, after all tasks have completed, to avoid concurrency issues; this approach will also reduce load on the database.

Then in your controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int employeeId, int[] itemIds)
{
    await _itemData.Assign(employeeId, itemIds);

    _log.Debug("Redirecting to work items");
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Assign` method needs to be async:

```
public async Task<bool> Assign(int employeeId, int[] itemIds)
{
    _log.Debug("Start assigning items");

    foreach (var itemId in itemIds)
    {
        _log.Debug($"Done assigning item {itemId}");
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<context>();

            Item item = await db.Items
                .Where(i => i.Id == itemId)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            item .EmployeeId= employeeId;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            _log.Debug($"Done assigning item {itemId}");
        }
    }

    _log.Debug("Done assigning items");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this does prevent `Assign` from returning to early, it is also hugely inefficient. Each database operation happens sequentially, which could take a significant time for a large number of items.

Comment: I don't see that as the main problem here. Just answering the question. Concurrent database operations aren't always faster than batch operations.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.ForEach` takes in an `Action<T>`. This means when you use an `async` delegate, it will turn that into and `async void`. Due to the signature being `void` and not `Task`, the delegate cannot be awaited. Thus marking it as `async` and using `await` inside gives you a false sense of correctness when in fact it is the opposite. You will have to change your `Assign` method to be `async Task` and then implement the suggestion from @Paulo Morgado.